# Weighing contrasts differently for unbalanced designs

Tags: mixed-model, contrasts

I'm using a mixed effect multilevel model for a crossed design in R. By design, one of my conditions has half the number of observations as the other condition (I am not talking about missing values here). Of interest is a contrast comparing the two. Here's the questions:

- Should I weigh the contrasts differently taking into account the number of observations?
- If yes, should more weight be given to the condition with larger number of observations since it has more bearing on the data or should I do the reverse to balance out the effect of number of observations?

Thanks,
Bonnie

Comment: Hi Bonnie, could you provide more details about your design? For example, you haven't explained whether you are running any type of factorial design, nor do we know the `IV`s and any relationships between them.

Comment: Hi Michelle, there are two single-task blocks (n = 80/block) and two switch-task blocks (n = 80/block). One of the analyses of interest, however, concerns comparing only a subset of trials in the switch-task block (when the task is repeated; n = 40/block) to the trials in the single block. This is where I have to deal with unequal number of trials in a contrast.